# Why are my Contacts icons on my phone with different colors?

Tags: contacts

Example:

[image: link]

Why is that? Does each color mean something? What is this?

Comment: What contact app are you using? What device? What Android version?

Comment: What do you mean Contact app? Device is GalaxyS2 Plus, 4.2.2 I believe. Not in my hands atm. It's my mom's phone heh.

Comment: like seriously, is that what questions have came to on Android SE?

Answer (score 4):

Purely random placeholder picture. The colors are quite likely different so it looks more colorful than having one single, boring placeholder picture on every contact.

Comment: The most random thing I've seen then.

Comment: Well, if it is purely for looks then it isn't THAT random. _Colorful_ is always better than _monotone and boring_.

Comment: Is it on all Android phones? The colorful contacts thingy?

Comment: Not that I know of, no, and I handle a lot of android devices at work...

Answer (score 3):

Nothing in the manual about it, and I haven't been able to determine any type of pattern with the colors. I think it's totally random to break up the monotony of the contacts list or something.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely that you have several different accounts configured on your phone, and have sync'd contacts with each of them.  One color back ground shows google contacts, another for hotmail, another for lotus notes, etc.  I have the same thing on my android.

Comment: Unlikely. I have only 1 account configured here (WebDAV, no Google etc.) but still have at least 6 colors present (and the screenshot in the question clearly shows 3 Google contacts with different colors). Good guess, though, as that at least would make some sense :)

Answer (score 1):

The varying colors of the contacts is not random on my phone (Galaxy S5).
Each time I add a contact it selects the next color in the sequence...
Blue, Green, Orange, Orange
Blue, Green, Orange, Orange...

It just looks untidy in the Contacts list, and I see no way of changing it - apart from adding a contact a few times until it's the color you want, and deleting the unwanted ones. You could also create some simple color pictures to assign to each profile picture (if you don't have their photo)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer has arrived. The different colors in your contacts represents the type of phone carrier and device an individual is using.

Comment: Source, please?

Comment: I somehow doubt that. First, how does the remote device become known locally? Even if you call me (or I you), I know you have a device but not which. Second, in my contacts I only have mobile and landline numbers, which would make 2 colors. But there are at least 6 colors present. So that doesn't match.

Answer (score -3):

It goes by who you contact the most.

Comment: Could you explain that a little more?